# Use RabbitMQ cluster with an Amazon elb

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I have set two ec2 instances that form a rabbitmqcluster. I want to reach the cluster via an ELB. For testing purpose I open for security group of both instances all tcp ports and http port.

On elb I listen on http 80 and tcp 5672 (sames terminations on instances)In the security group of elb all tcp ports are open and http 80

Health check is made via tcp on port 5672.

I use amqp.node node.js client
To connect to Elb I use this function :

```
require ('amqplib/callback_api').connect ('amqp://<endpoint_of_elb>,...)
```

But connection isn't established, I can't see why

(Note : 
- ec2 instances of rabbitmq are in the same AZ of ELB's vpc
-I also can't see why health check fails if I remove to listen on http 80 with elb)

Comment: Could be IP Tables. What AMI are you using?

Comment: What is your load balancer port and Instance port?

Comment: Uh I managed to make it run :) ->  maybe I shoukd take a look at my config...I have created an internal elb to make it work